# jQuery JSON response to selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I get a JSON response from the server as follows:

```
{"online":".uid-1,.uid-2,.uid-3","away":"","offline":".uid-4,.uid-5"}
```

Which means:

- Online: .uid-1, .uid-2, .uid-3
- Away: none
- Offline: .uid-4, .uid-5

And the jQuery code:

```
$.getJSON('users-get-online-status.php', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        if (key == 'online') {
            $(val).removeClass('status-online status-away status-offline').addClass('status-online');
        }
        if (key == 'away') {
            $(val).removeClass('status-online status-away status-offline').addClass('status-away');
        }
        if (key == 'offline') {
            $(val).removeClass('status-online status-away status-offline').addClass('status-offline');
        }
    });
 });
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="user uid-1"></div>
<div class="user uid-2"></div>
<div class="user uid-3"></div>
<div class="user uid-4"></div>
<div class="user uid-5"></div>
```

Now this has to walk through the JSON array and for each of the 3 statuses, remove any previously added status class and add the new one.

The problem here is how to put the `val` (uid classes already comma-separated) of the JSON entry inside the jQuery selector.

Comment: You're already putting the val into the selector... ?  And other than the away being a blank value, the other two are valid selector strings

Comment: @medk your code is already doing what you want

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra Ok sorry I was confused maybe it's not working for me because the DIVs are dynamically loaded with another AJAX request. So how to make the code take in consideration the newly added elements?

Comment: @medk put you code in ajax done method, after rendering the divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is already working as you require. That being said, you can DRY it up by removing the `$.each()` and simply using the `key` and `val` to build the required selectors and class names, like this:

```js
var data = {
  "online": ".uid-1,.uid-2,.uid-3",
  "away": "",
  "offline": ".uid-4,.uid-5"
}

// in the AJAX handler:
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
  $(val).removeClass('status-online status-away status-offline').addClass('status-' + key);
});
```

```css
.status-online {
  color: #0C0;
}

.status-away {
  color: #CCC;
}

.status-offline {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user uid-1">1</div>
<div class="user uid-2">2</div>
<div class="user uid-3">3</div>
<div class="user uid-4">4</div>
<div class="user uid-5">5</div>
```

Comment: if those three are the only classes `$(val)` will have, is it possible to replace `$(val).removeClass('status-online status-away status-offline').addClass('status-' + key);` with `$(val).attr('class', 'status-' + key);`?

Comment: Yep, that would work. If, as you say, they are the only classes.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ok sorry I was confused maybe it's not working for me because the DIVs are dynamically loaded with another AJAX request. So how to make the code take in consideration the newly added elements?

Comment: So long as you run this code *after* the AJAX requests that dynamically creates the `div` elements has completed, this should work fine.